# debugging STL in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

Based on posts found here and elsewhere, I attempted to speed up VS 2012 debugging (native C++, STL) by setting the `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP`, `_SECURE_SCL`, and `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` symbols.

No Luck.

I wrote a bare-bones test program that parses a large text file (100,000 rows, 100 columns), and ...

output in RELEASE mode:

```
     read 102595 lines in 6.051 seconds
```

output in DEBUG mode:

```
     read 102595 lines in 317.979 seconds    <==  50x slower, ouch !!!
```

Here's the full source code (C++ console app, no pre-compiled headers). The #define statements are not having any effect. Debug speed remains unbearably slow.  Any suggestions?

```
// testAppDebugSTL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define _SECURE_SCL             0
    #define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
    #define _NO_DEBUG_HEAP          1
#endif

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{

    std::ifstream                          f ("c:\\temp\\largeFile.csv");
    std::vector<std::string>               lines;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > tokenized_lines;
    size_t                                 num_lines = 0;

    clock_t tBeg = clock();
    while(!f.eof())
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(f, line);
        if (!f.eof())
        {
            lines.push_back(line);   num_lines++;
            std::stringstream        ss(line);
            std::string              token;
            std::vector<std::string> tokens;
            while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')) 
            {
                tokens.push_back(token);
            }
            tokenized_lines.push_back(tokens);
        }   
    }
    clock_t tEnd = clock();
    std::cout << "read " << num_lines << " lines in " <<  double(tEnd - tBeg)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know they're not having any effect? Did you make a measurement without these defines? At any rate, a debug build is always going to be substantially slower than a release one.

Comment: I have had debug builds run 100x slower, but blamed that on lack of inlining of small functions.

Comment: Advice: instead of trying to optimize debug mode, enable debug information in release mode.

Comment: Debug your code with reasonable data sets.  102595 lines is not going to diagnose a thousand times more bugs than 100 lines.  First battles are 1 and 2, once it is solid on 10 lines than the odds that it is still buggy get very low.  Always execute perf and capacity tests on the optimized build.

Comment: Are you sure these settings even take effect? Precompiled headers and the compiler commandline can interfere there! That said, the `while(!in.eof())` is almost a classic bug for which you'll find hundreds of explanations here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Yes, "almost", but not in this particular code.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question. It's extremely generic right now.

Comment: It's a very advanced version of the bug including a nifty workaround. Is that what you mean, @Lightness? ;-)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt lulz

Comment: Concerning the slowdown, if you can make any even halfway-reasonable approximation of the size of the `vector`, preallocating may save a good bit of time. Here, you I'd e.g. use `filesize/500` as rough estimate. Another way to save some time that is wasted in reallocations is to switch to `deque` and to avoid some copying by employing C++ move semantics.

Comment: Ran with and without #defines, no difference.  Running with a smaller dataset is certainly a workaround, but when something goes wrong in production it is better to work with the actual data (large) that caused the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change release mode to output debug symbols.  Debugging an optimized release build is a little weird at first, but you will get used to it (an ability to read some assembler helps).

Also remember to run the tests on small datasets first.

Comment: Not ideal because of var's that get optimized away, although I gather that newer VS versions have some extra features for debugging optimized releases lacking in VS 2012.  But still a good option.  Also through trial and error found that this test program would speed up 10x within Debug mode by simply setting [C/C++ ... Code Generation ... Basic Runtime Checks] to "/Default".   Also seemed to speed up changing /MDd to /MD (but not sure if that's a good idea).